# call setInterval for parallel execution

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, setinterval

I have a function `go()` which calls another, `some()` with time interval 500 milliseconds. How can I run it for execution parallel? If I call `go()` again, now it just reduce time interval.

```
function go() {
    setInterval(function() {
        some(massive)
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: Calling go() will add another interval which does the code every 500 milliseconds.  It does not change the interval of the first at all.  Not exactly sure what your question is really asking for, but maybe it has to do with the fact that you're not clearing the interval?

Comment: in fact now i have - when i call function go second time - it do method some just fuster time. But I need - when i call go() first time it call method some() which change array, and when call go() second time - method some start change the same array in parallel process.

Comment: When you call go() function second time, the function some() that started when you press it for the first time does not stop and parallel doing second some() function

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain this is what you're looking for, but it sounds like you need to clear the interval.

Consider the following code snippet:

```js
var i=0;
var interval=setInterval(function(){
  console.log(i++);
},500);

document.getElementById('clear-interval').onclick=clear;

function clear(){
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log('interval cleared');
}
```

```html
<button id='clear-interval'>Clear Interval</button>
```

In the snippet, the code continues to execute every 500ms until the clear() function is called.